Is it possible to train a neural network to feed into a Random Forest Classifier or any other type of classifier like XGBoost or Decision Tree?
I want to create a model architecture to predict future stock price movement as such:

The Goal of this model is to predict if the price will go UP or DOWN within the next 3 months.
I have tried a few models such as Logistic Regression, Neural Networks, XGBoost, etc. Ive received some decent results. Through using a Random Forest Classifier I have received the best results so far. I received some suggestions about using an AutoEncoder then feeding the encoded data into a decision tree. My only issue with this methodology is that I want the encoded data to have added value from the neural network not just a compressed version of the data. So my question is: How can I encode data through using a neural network then pass those values to a Random Forest Classifier to make the classification rather than using a final output layer using a sigmoid function as shown in the picture(Using Python, Keras, and SKlearn).
